# Any difference between IdentityServer3 and Thinktecutre.IdentityServer3?

Tags: security, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

When searching for IdentityServer on Nuget, I can see two recently published pacakages:
(1) Thinktecture.IdentityServer3 V1.6.3 (last published: 28/9/2015)
(2) IdentityServer3 V2.0.1 (last published: 6/9/2015)

What is the difference between the above two? Are there any additional features in one as compared to the other?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same project but the name was changed in the 2.x release to separate it from the brand/trademark of Thinktecture, as described here:

http://leastprivilege.com/2015/03/29/identityserver3-vnext/

> Probable the biggest change is the fact that we renamed the nuget package to simply IdentityServer3. We decided to remove the thinktecture registered trademark from the OSS project altogether (including the namespaces – so that’s another breaking change).

The release notes for 2.0 version describe the other changes:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/releases/tag/2.0.0